# VBA Excel: How to assign .txt file content to a string type variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I made a little sub in excel that sends an email according to the parameters you enter:

```
Sub Mail_LSP(mailsubject As String, consignee As String, coalcopy As String, mailbody As String)

Dim mlook As Outlook.MailItem

Set mlook = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mySubject = mailsubject
mlook.To = consignee
mlook.CC = coalcopy
mlook.Subject = mailsubject
mlook.Body = mailbody
mlook.Send

End Sub
```

I want to improve the mailbody parameter, Is there any way to assign the content of a .txt file to a variable, so I can then use this variable as a parameter to my procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using: `Open mailbody For Input As #1` and then `Line Input #1`

```
Sub Mail_LSP(mailsubject As String, consignee As String, coalcopy As String, mailbody As String)

Dim mlook As Outlook.MailItem
Dim linecontent As String
Dim mailcontent As String

Open mailbody For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, linecontent
    mailcontent = mailcontent & vbNewLine & linecontent & vbNewLine
Loop

Close #1

Set mlook = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mySubject = mailsubject
mlook.To = consignee
mlook.CC = coalcopy
mlook.Subject = mailsubject
mlook.Body = mailcontent
mlook.Send

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `FileSystemObject` :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Path = Range("E3")
Set filestream = fso.OpenTextFile(Path, 1)
contents = filestream.ReadAll()
Range("F4") = contents
End Sub
```